# How to replace div content to a specific div in this case

Tags: jquery

I am extracting the entire  html  present under div class **popup_content**

But when i am adding it again back i am loosing the div **popup_content**

This is my code

```
fetchandreplace()
function fetchandreplace()
{
    var vendoritemsid = '703';
    var dataaa = $("#popupinner"+vendoritemsid).find('.insidepopup').prop('outerHTML');
    $("#popupinner"+vendoritemsid).find('.popup_content').replaceWith(dataaa).trigger("create") ;
}
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/73/

Could you please let me know how to resolve this ??

Comment: use `.html()` instead of `replaceWith`

Comment: or find('.popup_content').empty().append(dataaa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are replacing popup_content div with new content in script.

```
     $("#popupinner"+vendoritemsid).find('.popup_content').html(dataaa);

      or 

     $("#popupinner"+vendoritemsid).find('.popup_content div:first-child').replaceWith(dataaa).trigger("create") ;
```

Comment: how can i make sure the the new content will be under popup_content (can't use append as it appends multiple times )

Answer (score 0):

You can use Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]

It might help you!!

```
$('.name-of-class').click( function() {
  $('[data-user-id="id"]').html('new content');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$("#popupinner"+vendoritemsid).find('.popup_content div:first-child').html(dataaa).trigger("create") ;
```